# How to add values based on years and get the maximum in xslt?

Tags: xslt

For example the source xml is :

```
<root>
<header>
    <row>
        <col id="0" attr1="RegionName">RegionName</col>
        <col id="1" attr1="2012">2012</col>
        <col id="2" attr1="2013">2013</col>
        <col id="3" attr1="2014">2014</col>
        <col id="4" attr1="2015">2015</col>
        <col id="5" attr1="2016">2016</col>
     </row>
</header>
<rows>
    <row id="1">
        <col id="0" attr1="RegionName">Region1</col>
        <col id="1" attr1="2012">40.989</col>
        <col id="2" attr1="2013">46.876</col>
        <col id="3" attr1="2014">53.299</col>
        <col id="4" attr1="2015">60.517</col>
        <col id="5" attr1="2016">69.149</col>
     </row>
    <row id="2">
        <col id="0" attr1="RegionName">Region2</col>
        <col id="1" attr1="2012">29.105</col>
        <col id="2" attr1="2013">30.869</col>
        <col id="3" attr1="2014">32.892</col>
        <col id="4" attr1="2015">35.259</col>
        <col id="5" attr1="2016">38.011</col>
    </row>
    <row id="3">
        <col id="0" attr1="RegionName">Region3</col>
        <col id="1" attr1="2012">17.274</col>
        <col id="2" attr1="2013">18.912</col>
        <col id="3" attr1="2014">20.627</col>
        <col id="4" attr1="2015">22.487</col>
        <col id="5" attr1="2016">24.492</col>
    </row>
    <row id="4">
        <col id="0" attr1="RegionName">Region4</col>
        <col id="1" attr1="2012">16.184</col>
        <col id="2" attr1="2013">17.507</col>
        <col id="3" attr1="2014">18.602</col>
        <col id="4" attr1="2015">20.135</col>
        <col id="5" attr1="2016">21.764</col>
    </row>
  </rows>
</root>
```

Now after xsl it should be something like below where it should sum all the values based on year for all the regions and calulate the max value out of it.

```
 ex for 2012 : Region1 + Region2 + Region3 + Region4  
                   40.989 + 29.105 + 17.274 + 16.184  = val1 

 ex for 2013 : Region1 + Region2 + Region3 + Region4  
                   46.876 + 30.869 + 18.912 + 17.507  = val2

 ex for 2014 : Region1 + Region2 + Region3 + Region4  
                   53.299 + 32.892 + 20.627 + 18.602  = val3

 ex for 2015 : Region1 + Region2 + Region3 + Region4  
                   60.517 + 35.259 + 22.487 + 20.135  = val4

 ex for 2016 : Region1 + Region2 + Region3 + Region4  
                   69.149 + 38.011 + 24.492 + 21.764  = val5
```

I want max of `(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5)` as my output in a variable name `MaxValue`.

```
<xsl:variable name='MaxValue'></xsl:variable>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can sum all columns with the same id using an expression like `sum(//rows/row/col[@id=//header/row/col[@attr1='2012']/@id])` (sums the cols for 2012). It's quite simple to write a XSLT for that. What does your desired output look like? Where do you want to place the results?

Answer (score 0):

Your values can also be calculated with XPath expressions. If you wish to present your result data in a format like this:

```
<result>
   <subtotal region="2012">103.55199999999999</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2013">114.16400000000002</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2014">125.42</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2015">138.398</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2016">153.416</subtotal>
   <max-value>153.416</max-value>
</result>
```

The result above can be obtained with this **XSLT 1.0** stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="header/row/col">
        <subtotal region="{@attr1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id &gt; 0][@id=current()[@attr1=current()/@attr1]/@id])"/>
        </subtotal>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <result>
            <xsl:variable name="maxValue">
                <xsl:for-each select="header/row/col[@id &gt; 0]">
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id &gt; 0][@id=current()[@attr1=current()/@attr1]/@id])"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="header/row/col[@id>0]"/>
            <max-value><xsl:value-of select="$maxValue"/></max-value>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `maxValue` variable is calculated by adding the values for each region, sorting them as numbers in ascending order, and getting the last value.

If you are using **XSLT 2.0** you don't have to do this since you could use the `max()` function. These are your `val1` ... `val5` variables in absolute XPath expressions and the `maxValue` being calculated with the `max()` function.

```
<xsl:variable name="val1" select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id=//header/row/col[@attr1='2012']/@id])"/>
<xsl:variable name="val2" select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id=//header/row/col[@attr1='2013']/@id])"/>
<xsl:variable name="val3" select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id=//header/row/col[@attr1='2014']/@id])"/>
<xsl:variable name="val4" select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id=//header/row/col[@attr1='2015']/@id])"/>
<xsl:variable name="val5" select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id=//header/row/col[@attr1='2016']/@id])"/>

<xsl:variable name="maxValue" select="max(($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,$val5))"/>
```

Here is a **XSLT 2.0** solution using an XPath 2.0 `for` expression to obtain the totals for the `max` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="header/row/col">
        <subtotal region="{@attr1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//rows/row/col[@id &gt; 0][@id=current()[@attr1=current()/@attr1]/@id])"/>
        </subtotal>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <result>
            <xsl:variable name="maxValue" 
                 select="max(for $col in header/row/col return sum(//rows/row/col[@id &gt; 0][@id=$col[@attr1=$col/@attr1]/@id]))"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="header/row/col[@id>0]"/>
            <max-value><xsl:value-of select="$maxValue"/></max-value>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. but my requirement is to get the max number out of Val1, val2,var3,val4 and val5.                     <result>
   <subtotal region="2012">103.55199999999999</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2013">114.16400000000002</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2014">125.42</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2015">138.398</subtotal>
   <subtotal region="2016">153.416</subtotal>
   <total>634.9499999999998</total>
</result>

Comment: Sorry. I must have confused the totals with the sums :) I updated the answer, which now gets the maximum result.